# How to convert from Newton.Json.Linq.JToken to byte[]?

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I am attempting to retrieve a byte array from a Jtoken:

```
byte[] PDF;
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonData);
if (results != null)
{
    JArray docList = (JArray)results.SelectToken("");
    foreach (JToken doc in docList)
    {
         PDF = string.IsNullOrEmpty(doc["PDF"].ToString()) ? null : doc["PDF"];
    }
}
```

But I am receiving this error: "cannot implicitly convert type 'newtonsoft.json.linq.Jtoken to byte[]. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

How can I convert Newton.Json.Linq.JToken to byte[]?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [explicit conversion operator](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_op_Explicit_31.htm) provided for `JToken`:

```
PDF = (byte [])(string.IsNullOrEmpty(doc["PDF"].ToString()) ? null : doc["PDF"]);
```

Or, use [`ToObject<T>()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1.htm):

```
PDF = (doc["PDF"] == null ? null : doc["PDF"].ToObject<byte []>());
```

Comment: Thank you :) I knew it was going to be something very simple.